# How to upgrade/downgrade subscription in an android application using Unity IAP

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Right now my application is in Internal testing in the google play console.
I have 3 months,6 months, and 1-year subscriptions in the application.
I already bought 6 months subscription and now I am trying to upgrade my subscription to 12 months.

I have also attached the bit of the code, where I am checking if the user has any existing subscription or not by checking the presence of receipt.
if there is no existing subscription then I am directly buying the subscription
using "BuyProductID(_1YearSubscription);",
else
I am trying to upgrade it to the new subscription using
"  SubscriptionManager.UpdateSubscriptionInGooglePlayStore(oldProduct, m_StoreController.products.WithID(_1YearSubscription), (string msg1, string msg2) =>
{

```
            IgoogleplayStoreExtention.UpdateSubscription(oldProduct, m_StoreController.products.WithID(_1YearSubscription), GooglePlayStoreProrationMode.ImmediateWithoutProration);
        });"
```

but I am getting an error that says

"2021-06-17 10:34:09.811 26172 26232 Info Unity Error: the product that will be updated does not have a valid receipt: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."(this is from android logcat).

what exactly is the issue and how can u fix it??

unity version is 2019.4.18

Thanx for the answer in advance.

```
public void Buy1YearSubscription()
    {
 
        print("trying to buy 12 months of subscription");
 
 
 
 
        bool alreadyHaveSomeSubscription = false;
        Product oldProduct = m_StoreController.products.WithID(_1YearSubscription);
 
 
        foreach (Product p in m_StoreController.products.all)
        {
            GooglePurchaseData data = new GooglePurchaseData(p.receipt);
 
            if (p.hasReceipt)
            {
                alreadyHaveSomeSubscription = true;
                oldProduct = m_StoreController.products.WithID(data.json.productId);
                GooglePurchaseData data2 = new GooglePurchaseData(oldProduct.receipt);
 
                print("Has the reciept of----->" + data2.json.productId);
 
                break;
            }
        }
 
        if (!alreadyHaveSomeSubscription)
        {
            print("no previous subscription");
            BuyProductID(_1YearSubscription);
        }
        else
        {
 
            print("upgrading to 1year");
            SubscriptionManager.UpdateSubscriptionInGooglePlayStore(oldProduct, m_StoreController.products.WithID(_1YearSubscription), (string msg1, string msg2) =>
            {
 
                IgoogleplayStoreExtention.UpdateSubscription(oldProduct, m_StoreController.products.WithID(_1YearSubscription), GooglePlayStoreProrationMode.ImmediateWithoutProration);
            });
 
 
        }
    }
```